# Bitcoin cash and Bitcoin

Tags: blockchain-fork, bitcoin-cash

If I have 1 bitcoin now, do I end up having 1 bitcoin and 1 bitcoin cash after the BCC hard fork? If yes, how do I make sure I have these two in my wallets? Currently I control my private keys.